# Apache Drill sqlline in embedded mode is crashing on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, apache-drill

When issuing the following command.

```
bin/sqline -u 'jdbc:drill:drillbit=local' -e 'select * from cp.`employee.json`'
```

I get the following Java error messages.  I've searched elsewhere and am hoping someone can point out an obvious fix or point me in the right direction

```
Error: Failure in connecting to Drill: org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcException: CONNECTION : java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException (state=,code=0)
```

java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Failure in connecting to Drill: org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcException: CONNECTION : java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.(DrillConnectionImpl.java:178)
at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newDrillConnection(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:67)
at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillFactory.newConnection(DrillFactory.java:67)
at org.apache.calcite.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.connect(UnregisteredDriver.java:138)
at org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:75)
at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:135)
at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:192)
at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1364)
at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1244)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sqlline.ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(ReflectiveCommandHandler.java:38)
at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:730)
at sqlline.SqlLine.initArgs(SqlLine.java:410)
at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:515)
at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:267)
at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:206)
Caused by: org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.RpcException: CONNECTION : java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
at org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.user.UserClient$2.connectionFailed(UserClient.java:315)
at org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.user.QueryResultHandler$ChannelClosedHandler.connectionFailed(QueryResultHandler.java:396)
at org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.ConnectionMultiListener$ConnectionHandler.operationComplete(ConnectionMultiListener.java:119)
at org.apache.drill.exec.rpc.ConnectionMultiListener$ConnectionHandler.operationComplete(ConnectionMultiListener.java:77)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:481)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:420)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:122)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.connect(AbstractNioChannel.java:241)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1226)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:539)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:524)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.connect(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:47)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:539)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:524)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.connect(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:50)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:539)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:524)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:506)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:970)
Thank you

Comment: So, do you have a server called `Drill` ?  If so can you ping it from the above machine?

Comment: Let me try using the machine name.  Hopefully it's something that simple.  Thank you. Will get back tomorrow with an update.

Comment: Sorry, the machine is not called drill.  I'm using the connection string as described on Apache Drill's documentation.  Drill is the name of the program

Answer (score 0):

sqlline fails where machine is installed.  But works on client.  Which is fine for my use case.